Is the set of equidistance between two points always a curve?
Consider a strictly convex normed plane $V$. If you like, you can consider just some $p$-norm for $p \in  (1, \infty)$. I can find loads of literature references (For example here and its bibliography) to the fact that the equisets $\{x  \in V: \|x-a\| = \|x-b\|\}$ for $a \ne b$ are always simple curves. You can convince yourself of this by playing with this toy I made.

However, I can find no proof written down anywhere. That suggests that it is not too hard to prove. Can anyone give me some tips?

This is easier to prove for strictly convex norms (for instance, $p$-norms, $1<p<\infty$, although the cases $p=1, p=\infty$ are again easy). You should state what exactly you mean by a "simple curve", I assume, a subset homeomorphic to  the real line. But maybe you mean a smooth 1-dimensional submanifold? For this, you should assume smoothness of the norm.

You can use the term "generalized perpendicular bissector". See here for convex norms.
